# ios swift method parameters

Tags: ios, swift

I'm reading the swift getting started apple's guide. And they give the following code :

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

Why are they two parameters name ? coder and aDecoder.

I don't understand why we don't use this syntax that works to :

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder)
```

Thank you.

Comment: external/internal parameter names: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166

Comment: In practice, use the following underscore trick to avoid the idiotic "named-named" argument style - which is the one and only disastrous idea in Swift.  `private func _hide(a:Bool, _ b:Bool, _ c:Bool, _ d:Bool)`  Note that you use an underscore for all of them but not for the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coder` is external parameter name. It is used when calling method:

```
SomeClass(coder: someCoder)
```

`aDecoder`is local parameter name. It is used inside method:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

You may specify just local parameter name:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder)
```

In this case external parameter name automatically takes the same value `coder`.
The main use is readability. Your example is not very obvious. Lets take a better one from the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166) posted by **Eric D**:

```
func sayHello(to person: String, and anotherPerson: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(person) and \(anotherPerson)!"
}
print(sayHello(to: "Bill", and: "Ted"))
```

This is more readable (better explains what method is doing) when calling `sayHello` method than

```
func sayHello(person: String, anotherPerson: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(person) and \(anotherPerson)!"
}
print(sayHello(person: "Bill", anotherPerson: "Ted"))
```

Of course you can write

```
func sayHello(to: String, and: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(to) and \(and)!"
}
print(sayHello(to: "Bill", and: "Ted"))
```

But in this case local variables are using bad naming style